# Adding support library with resources "Add to build path" not available

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to import v7 support library in my Eclipse workspace using [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res). The step 5 is not doable because "Add to build path" is not available.

```
In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and
select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7
appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar and 
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.
```

My understanding is that `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` gets added to build path automatically and I can skip this step without any worries. Am I correct?

Comment: In the latest versions, If you copy into libs folder it automatically does for you but If you're build version is below 3.0 then manually u should do

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Copy what into which libs folder? What should I do manually?

Comment: If you copy jars into libs, adding of jars to build path to be done manually if your build version of android is 3.0